# react-native-fcm How to send fcm_token to rails api server

Tags: react-native, react-native-fcm

I want to send fcm_token(device_token) to my rails api server.
I get fcm_token by FCM.getFCMToken();

However, 
    const device_token = FCM.getFCMToken(); don't work.

I need variables of fcm_token like 
    const device_token = "xxxx"
.

Do you have any qlue?
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`FCM.getFCMToken()` returns a Promise.

```
FCM.getFCMToken().then(device_token => {
  console.log(device_token);
  // Send token to your server here.
});
```

Or, the ECMAScript 6 equivalent:

```
const device_token = await FCM.getFCMToken();
// Send token to your server here.
```

Comment: thanks.However I need global variable, I did like that    
    FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
          global.device_token = token;
    });